# VSTO VB tree view Node = Sheet tab color

Tags: vba, vb.net, vsto, customtaskpane

I'm building a VSTO project with a simple action pane containing a treeview. Coming from VBA, things are similar, but not the same and I'm a bit confused.

What I want to do is load all sheets to the tree view, and give each node the color of the respective sheet. I'm getting an error at the commented line below, I believe the error is coming from the fact that the N.BackColor is in RGB and SH.Tab.Color is in colorcode.

**The question is should I use a different property to get the same color type, or do I need to cast it. If I need to cast it please help me with this, as most of the documentation is in C#, and I'm not sure where to look for an answer**

```
Private Sub ActionPane_SheetSearch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim SH As Excel.Worksheet, N As TreeNode

        With Me
            .Width = 200
        End With

        With Me.TreeView1
            .ItemHeight = 20
            For Each SH In Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets
                N = .Nodes.Add(SH.Name)
                N.Tag = SH.CodeName
                'N.BackColor = SH.Tab.Color
            Next
        End With
End Sub
```

Also with `.Width = 200` i'm trying to customize the with of the action pane, but it's ignoring the code or I'm not doing it correclty.
I tried setting the starting width at the begining as well, it does not respond.

**Please let me know how can I set the starting with, and also set the default position to left instead of right.**

```
Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

        Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(taskPane)
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = True
        taskPane.Width = 400
        taskPane.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: If there's no tab color set then `SH.Tab.Color` will return `False` (otherwise you will get a Long)

Comment: `ActionsPane` has a `Width` property and see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/actions-pane-overview?view=vs-2022#:~:text=Pane%22%5D.Width%20%3D%20200%3B-,Reposition%20the%20actions%20pane,-You%20cannot%20directly

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Custom task panes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2022) instead. The [DockPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customtaskpane.dockposition) property sets an enumerated value specifying the docked position of a `CustomTaskPane` object. The [Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customtaskpane.width) property sets the width of the task pane specified by the `CustomTaskPane` object.